# How can I set a boolean so that it is not necessarily true but not default to false in the ViewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am making an iPhone app and want to use an 'if' statement and a boolean to set default values in some instances but not others... is this possible?

Are there alternative options if it is not possible?

EDIT:
In the MainViewController.m I have:

```
@interface MainViewController (){
    BOOL moveOver;
}
[...]
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", computerSpeed];
    }
}
[...]
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    moveOver = true;    
}
```

EDIT: The problem that it is redefined when the ViewDidLoad still persists... I need a statement that will not redefine when the ViewDidLoad runs (sorry for the unclarity)

EDIT: I have something that I feel like is much closer to working...

In the ViewDidLoad I have:

```
if (playToInt != 10  || computerMoveSpeed != 3) {   
    moveOver = TRUE;
}
```

which connects to my created method, gameLoop.  It has

```
if (moveOver == false) {
    computerMoveSpeed = 3;        
    playToInt = 10;    
}
```

I have two UITextFields and typed 10 and 3 in them... does this not set it to the default?  It seems to set the default to 0 for both, how do I change this?

Comment: you need to expand your question is too vague, if you can post some code to exemplify your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize it in the constructor one way or another.

It sounds like you want more than two states in which case you can use an enum or even an integer 0-1-2 for false, not quite true, and true.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the previous answer you could also create an `enum` to handle more than one states.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your boolean value in a NSNumber which can be nil, true, or false (nil meaning uninitialized).